# trying to apply gaussian blur to image and save as a new image to upload in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, alamofire

I have a function that takes an image and blurs it and then uploads both to a server. The problem I'm having is making and uploading the blurred image.

```
func uploadPic (imagee: UIImage) {

//blur
let imageCopyy = imagee.af_imageFiltered( withCoreImageFilter: "CIGuassianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius": 25] ) as! UIImage

//upload blurred pic
post(image: imageCopy)
```

Thats the part of the function that blurs the image, the problem is that the new blurred UIImage is nil and crashes, and if I dont do a force unwrap it doesnt compile.

```
upload pic(imagee: imageView.image!)
```

is how im calling the function in the first place

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'CIImage'. Its confusing me because I cant figure out what type of image its actually returning

Comment: func af_imageFiltered(withCoreImageFilter name: String, parameters: [String : Any]? = default) -> UIImage?

Comment: So it returns an optional image  `UIImage?`. You need to use `if let imageCopy = imagee.af_imageFiltered(withCoreImageFilter: "CIGaussianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius": 25]) { post(image: imageCopy)`

Comment: The problem, is the name of the filter. You are passing `"CIGuassianBlur"`  but it should be `"CIGaussianBlur"`

Comment: Also, make sure that u are using CIImage when u are applying the filter

Comment: @LeoDabus is right. I'd also recommend in situations like this that you break down that line of code into individual pieces. You are doing *at least* 3 things in defining what `imageCopyy` (or is this a second typo and should be `imageCopy`) is. In fact, shouldn't it be `image` and not `imagee` in the separate line of code?